# Ошибка SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: python, windows-10, ssl, pytest

При запуске теста в PyTest возникает ошибка:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_114.0.5735 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: CA certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Пошуршал интернеты, решения пока не смог найти. Запускаю на Win 10.

Что уже попробовал:

1. https://qna.habr.com/q/1165446 отсюда последний коммент (создание нового pip.ini);
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate вариант отсюда, касающиеся Win (обновление сертификатов с помощью команды pip install pip-system-certs)
3. В тестовом фреймворке уже был установлен verify=False на всех методах запросов.
4. Пробовал вручную указывать путь для драйвера chrome в локальной папке, заместо менеджера драйверов.
5. Были ещё некоторые, связанные с ручным обновлением сертификатов Win, но что именно делал уже не воспроизведу.

В качестве причины проблемы могу предположить, что установленные сертификаты Charles и Proxyman сломали сертификаты Window, но это неточно. Знает кто-нибудь, как можно починить ошибку?

Более подробный стэктрейс:

```py
self = <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0x0000026356B0F7F0>
request = <PreparedRequest [GET]>, stream = False
timeout = Timeout(connect=None, read=None, total=None), verify = True
cert = None, proxies = OrderedDict()

    def send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):
        """Sends PreparedRequest object. Returns Response object.
    
        :param request: The :class:`PreparedRequest <PreparedRequest>` being sent.
        :param stream: (optional) Whether to stream the request content.
        :param timeout: (optional) How long to wait for the server to send
            data before giving up, as a float, or a :ref:`(connect timeout,
            read timeout) <timeouts>` tuple.
        :type timeout: float or tuple or urllib3 Timeout object
        :param verify: (optional) Either a boolean, in which case it controls whether
            we verify the server's TLS certificate, or a string, in which case it
            must be a path to a CA bundle to use
        :param cert: (optional) Any user-provided SSL certificate to be trusted.
        :param proxies: (optional) The proxies dictionary to apply to the request.
        :rtype: requests.Response
        """
    
        try:
            conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
        except LocationValueError as e:
            raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
    
        self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
        url = self.request_url(request, proxies)
        self.add_headers(request, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
    
        chunked = not (request.body is None or 'Content-Length' in request.headers)
    
        if isinstance(timeout, tuple):
            try:
                connect, read = timeout
                timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=connect, read=read)
            except ValueError as e:
                # this may raise a string formatting error.
                err = ("Invalid timeout {}. Pass a (connect, read) "
                       "timeout tuple, or a single float to set "
                       "both timeouts to the same value".format(timeout))
                raise ValueError(err)
        elif isinstance(timeout, TimeoutSauce):
            pass
        else:
            timeout = TimeoutSauce(connect=timeout, read=timeout)
    
        try:
            if not chunked:
                resp = conn.urlopen(
                    method=request.method,
                    url=url,
                    body=request.body,
                    headers=request.headers,
                    redirect=False,
                    assert_same_host=False,
                    preload_content=False,
                    decode_content=False,
                    retries=self.max_retries,
                    timeout=timeout
                )
    
            # Send the request.
            else:
                if hasattr(conn, 'proxy_pool'):
                    conn = conn.proxy_pool
    
                low_conn = conn._get_conn(timeout=DEFAULT_POOL_TIMEOUT)
    
                try:
                    low_conn.putrequest(request.method,
                                        url,
                                        skip_accept_encoding=True)
    
                    for header, value in request.headers.items():
                        low_conn.putheader(header, value)
    
                    low_conn.endheaders()
    
                    for i in request.body:
                        low_conn.send(hex(len(i))[2:].encode('utf-8'))
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                        low_conn.send(i)
                        low_conn.send(b'\r\n')
                    low_conn.send(b'0\r\n\r\n')
    
                    # Receive the response from the server
                    try:
                        # For Python 2.7, use buffering of HTTP responses
                        r = low_conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
                    except TypeError:
                        # For compatibility with Python 3.3+
                        r = low_conn.getresponse()
    
                    resp = HTTPResponse.from_httplib(
                        r,
                        pool=conn,
                        connection=low_conn,
                        preload_content=False,
                        decode_content=False
                    )
                except:
                    # If we hit any problems here, clean up the connection.
                    # Then, reraise so that we can handle the actual exception.
                    low_conn.close()
                    raise
    
        except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
            raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    
        except MaxRetryError as e:
            if isinstance(e.reason, ConnectTimeoutError):
                # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
                if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
                    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):
                raise RetryError(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, _ProxyError):
                raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
    
            if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
                # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
>               raise SSLError(e, request=request)
E               requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_114.0.5735 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: CA certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:997)')))

..\..\..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py:514: SSLError
```